# what is template-name.php

Tags: templates

A while back I found that there was a reason to name a template like so

template-name.php

For the life of me, I can't remember what it was for. I thought it was so that WordPress would automatically pick up that template so that you would not have to set the page template when creating the post. I have been looking in the codex for an hour and can't find it. Do you know what the logic is behind this?

Comment: There is no logic; you can name your templates `krafutzel.php` and they will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always name them like so: page-name.php; This keeps my page templates nicely together + in some cases this can make your code easier, for example...

```
<?php // Get the file called loop-page.php
get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>
```

A quick Google revealed also this http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/organizing-and-naming-your-themes-template-files-for-clarity-and-convenience/

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it on codex - [Page Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display)

> ### Quote from Codex -
>
> - **custom template file** - The Page Template assigned to the Page. See `get_page_templates()`.
> - **page-{slug}.php** - If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use `page-recent-news.php`
> - **page-{id}.php** - If the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use `page-6.php`
> - **page.php**
> - **index.php**

Comment: yes, there was some good information posted by Amit and Marcup. I thought you could name templates by the name of a custom post type and WordPress would pick up that template automatically.  I think maybe the page-name.php might do that.

Comment: Yeah. You can use page-customposttype.php, single-customposttype.php, etc.

Comment: Yes, `page-ID.php` then no need to manually assigne page template on save.

Comment: for some reason when I try this, it doesn't work. Here is what I thought. If I have a custom post type called "gallery" I should be able to set up a file called page-gallery.php and wordpress would pick it up automatically so I would not need to set the template name on the page. But when I try that logic, it doesn't work. I could have sworn I did this before